# SqlAlchemy linking tables

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

So with SQLAlchemy i want to create 3 tables

```
Obj
obj_id | obj_type

User
user_id | obj_id | name | mail 

Society
society_id | obj_id | name
```

so lets say i push 3 elements and i want to have something like this :

```
Obj
obj_id | obj_type
1      | society
2      | user
3      | society

User
user_id | obj_id | name | mail 
1       | 2      | John | john.smith@700.com

Society
society_id | obj_id | name
1          | 1      | Google
2          | 3      | Facebook
```

how do i construct my code and add / commit  so i link my tables?

```
class Obj(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'objects'
    obj_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    obj_type = Column(String(30))

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    obj_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('objects.obj_id'))
    name = Column(String(100), default=None)
    mail = Column(String(200), default=None)
    objects = relationship("Obj", back_populates="users")

class Society(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'society'
    society_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    obj_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("objects.obj_id"))
    name = Column(String(100), default=None)
    objects = relationship("Obj", back_populates="society")
    people = relationship("People", back_populates="society")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table structure resembles [joined table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance), with `objects.obj_type` as the [discriminator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/glossary.html#term-discriminator):

```
In [2]: class Obj(Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'objects'
   ...:     obj_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...:     obj_type = Column(String(30))
   ...:     __mapper_args__ = {
   ...:         'polymorphic_identity': 'object',
   ...:         'polymorphic_on': obj_type
   ...:     }
   ...:     

In [3]: class User(Obj):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'users'
   ...:     user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...:     obj_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('objects.obj_id'))
   ...:     name = Column(String(100), default=None)
   ...:     mail = Column(String(200), default=None)
   ...:     __mapper_args__ = {
   ...:         'polymorphic_identity': 'user'
   ...:     }
   ...:     

In [4]: class Society(Obj):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'society'
   ...:     society_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...:     obj_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("objects.obj_id"))
   ...:     name = Column(String(100), default=None)
   ...:     ...
   ...:     __mapper_args__ = {
   ...:         'polymorphic_identity': 'society'
   ...:     }
   ...:
```

Note that you don't need the objects relationships in the child classes in order to link them to their related Obj. You can access the parent's attributes as you would normally when inheriting.

Adding the 3 elements:

```
In [6]: session.add(User(name='John', mail='john.smith@700.com'))

In [7]: session.add_all([Society(name='Google'), Society(name='Facebook')])

In [8]: session.commit()
```

And checking that we can [polymorphically](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/glossary.html#term-polymorphically) query all Objs:

```
In [9]: session.query(Obj).all()
Out[9]: 
[<__main__.User at 0x7f37b5aaa780>,
 <__main__.Society at 0x7f37b5aaab00>,
 <__main__.Society at 0x7f37b5aaacc0>]
```

You can also check what the tables actually contain:

```
In [10]: session.query(Obj.__table__).all()
Out[10]: [(1, 'user'), (2, 'society'), (3, 'society')]

In [11]: session.query(User.__table__).all()
Out[11]: [(1, 1, 'John', 'john.smith@700.com')]

In [12]: session.query(Society.__table__).all()
Out[12]: [(1, 2, 'Google'), (2, 3, 'Facebook')]
```